# Insert Image and set to circle in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

This is my code to insert image to canvas..

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addTexttitle()" type="button" class="text-left btn-block btn white">Set Image To Circle</button>
<input type="file" id="file">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
        <a href='' id='txt' target="_blank">Click Me!</a>
        <br />
        <img id="preview" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/javasalden/yn04k565/

how to complete button:

```
<button onclick="addTexttitle()" type="button" class="text-left btn-block btn white">Set Image To Circle</button>
```

when I click and image/element will be CIRCLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clipTo function

```
img.set({
 clipTo: function (ctx) {
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
 }
});
```

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/yn04k565/1/), the radius is half of uploaded image

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created one example, please have a look at it, this is definatley be useful for you.

```js
var createCache = function(requestFunction) {
    var cache = {};
    return function(key, callback) {
        if (!cache[key]) {
            cache[key] = $.Deferred(function(defer) {
                requestFunction(defer, key);
            }).promise();
        }
        return cache[key].done(drawImg);
    };
};


var loadImage = createCache(function(defer, url) {
    var image = new Image();
    function cleanUp() {
       image.onload = image.onerror = null;
    }
    
    defer.then(cleanUp, cleanUp);
    image.onload = function() {
        defer.resolve(url);
    };
    image.onerror = defer.reject;
    image.src = url;
});


var drawImg = function(img) {
    var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        image = new Image();
    
    
    image.src = img;
    tmpCanvas.width = image.width*2;
    tmpCanvas.height = image.height*2;
    
    // draw the cached images to temporary canvas and return the context
    tmpCtx.save();
        tmpCtx.beginPath();
            tmpCtx.arc(2*24, 2*24, 2*24, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        tmpCtx.closePath();
        tmpCtx.clip();

    tmpCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 4*24+2, 4*24+2);
    
        tmpCtx.beginPath();
            tmpCtx.arc(0, 0, 2, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            tmpCtx.clip();
        tmpCtx.closePath();
    tmpCtx.restore();

    $('body').append(tmpCanvas);
};


var cacheImgs = function() {
    var imgs = [
       
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/19/15/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg'
    ];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var img = loadImage(imgs[i])/*.done(drawImg(imgs[i]))*/;
        // .done callback is what sends the canvases to where they need to go
    }
}
cacheImgs();
```

```css
canvas { float: left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a fabric.js solution to the problem.

Comment: may be he didnt mensioned so i thought that this might be useful. and it was working fine so.

Comment: Thanks bro @Blindman67 for updating the code and removing unnecessary consoles.